# Sharepoint Alerts not sending emails

Tags: 2010, alert, incoming-email

I have a problem that  I can't seem to understand. I have a user who has set up alerts for a library with the settings shown below:

[image]

For some reason I cannot understand, the user with the issue does not get an alert when an item is added or when any other action is taken on the library. However, when other users, including me, set an alert with the same settings on the same library we get notified with no issues. We are connected to an SMTP server that does the sending.

**Things we have tried**

- We checked to see if it may be a permissions issue but it is not.
- We also tried deleting the user's alert and recreating it but to no avail.
- The user also checked their Outlook rules but there is none that would apply and we have verified that the user is able to receive mail from SharePoint.

Is there anything else that I can try to do in order to fix the issue? Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
The user informed me that they were setting an **alert** on a **Folder** and **not** a **Library**

Comment: How have you verified that the user is able to receive mail from SharePoint?

Comment: Is the user setting the alert for themselves? No one is attempting to set it on their behalf?

Comment: @ErikPerez Yes. When the user created an alert on the library the user received a confirmation stating that the user has successfully created an alert.

Comment: @GeorgeGrainger Correct. The user is setting the alert for themselves on the Library and no one else.

Comment: Is it just one user with the problem? Or, more than one?  And, have you checked if alerts work for the that user in a different site collection?

Comment: @ErikPerez yes it is only one user. I tested it with another user with the same perms on the site and they receive alerts. Weird thing is the user with the issue contacted me and said that it has been fixed. When asked about the fix, they said that it just started working.